# PHP application with remote MySQL and nginx load balancers ends up with a huge page load execution time

Tags: nginx, centos, mysql, php, load-balancing

I was reading and trying to set up a proper load balancer with PHP application using nginx.

Now from the documentation I understand that I need to run on every server instance PHP and nginx, then use a remote SQL to connect all the upstream servers so there will be the same content server across all the servers.

The problem is when I'm using a local SQL on the same server the page load goes around 0.08s, while on the remote SQL server which has 1gbit port speed, 8GB ram and is in the same city as 2 other upstream servers page load gets around 1.8 - 2s. I understand that there might be a latency issue, but then how people load-balance stuff and make it work fast as if the database was on the same server as the application?

Comment: What is the latency between the application server and the database server? Even a few milliseconds is multiplied by the number of queries.

Comment: One page should make one connection.  If you are doing multiple connections for a single page, that could be the problem.